# Spring Boot equivalent to XML multi-database configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, multi-database

I would like to port two projects to Spring Boot 1.1.6. The are each part of a larger project. They both need to make SQL connections to 1 of 7 production databases per web request based region. One of them persists configuration setting to a Mongo database. They are both functional at the moment but the SQL configuration is XML based and the Mongo is application.properties based. I'd like to move to either xml or annotation before release to simplify maintenance.

This is my first try at this forum, I may need some guidance in that arena as well. I put the multi-database tag on there. Most of those deal with two connections open at a time. Only one here and only the URL changes. Schema and the rest are the same.

In XML Fashion ...

```
@Controller
public class CommonController {
    private CommonService CommonService_i; 

    @RequestMapping(value = "/rest/Practice/{enterprise_id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)

public @ResponseBody List<Map<String, Object>> getPracticeList(@PathVariable("enterprise_id")   String enterprise_id){

    CommonService_i = new CommonService(enterprise_id);
    return CommonService_i.getPracticeList();
}

@Service
public class CommonService {
    private ApplicationContext ctx = null;
    private JdbcTemplate template = null;
    private DataSource datasource = null;
    private SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = null;

public CommonService(String enterprise_id) {
    ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("database-beans.xml");
    datasource = ctx.getBean(enterprise_id, DataSource.class);
    template = new JdbcTemplate(datasource);
}
```

Each time a request is made, a new instance of the required service is created with the appropriate database connection.

In the spring boot world, I've come across one article that extended TomcatDataSourceConfiguration.
http://xantorohara.blogspot.com/2013/11/spring-boot-jdbc-with-multiple.html That at least allowed me to create a java configuration class however, I cannot come up with a way to change the prefix for the ConfigurationProperties per request like I am doing with the XML above. I can set up multiple configuration classes but the @Qualifier("00002") in the DAO has to be a static value.  //The value for annotation attribute Qualifier.value must be a constant expression

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "Region1")
public class DbConfigR1  extends TomcatDataSourceConfiguration {

   @Bean(name = "dsRegion1") 
    public DataSource dataSource() { 
        return super.dataSource(); 
    } 

    @Bean(name = "00001") 
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dsRegion1) { 
        return new JdbcTemplate(dsRegion1); 
    } 
}
```

On the Mongo side, I am able to define variables in the configurationProperties class and, if there is a matching entry in the appropriate application.properties file, it overwrites it with the value in the file. If not, it uses the value in the code. That does not work for the JDBC side. If you define a variable in your config classes, that value is what is used. (yeah.. I know it says mondoUrl)

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.mongo")
public class MongoConnectionProperties {

    private String mondoURL = "localhost";

    public String getMondoURL() {
        return mondoURL;
    }

    public void setMondoURL(String mondoURL) {
        this.mondoURL = mondoURL;
    }
```

There was a question anwsered today that got me a little closer. [Spring Boot application.properties value not populating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25764459/spring-boot-application-properties-value-not-populating) The answer showed me how to at least get @Value to function. With that, I can set up a dbConfigProperties class that grabs the @Value. The only issue is that the value grabbed by @Value is only available in when the program first starts. I'm not certain how to use that other than seeing it in the console log when the program starts. What I do know now is that, at some point, in the @Autowired of the dbConfigProperties class, it does return the appropriate value. By the time I want to use it though, it is returning ${spring.datasource.url} instead of the value.

Ok... someone please tell me that @Value is not my only choice. I put the following code in my controller. I'm able to reliably retrieve one value, Yay. I suppose I could hard code each possible property name from my properties file in an argument for this function and populate a class. I'm clearly doing something wrong.

```
private String url;  
//private String propname = "${spring.datasource.url}"; //can't use this

@Value("${spring.datasource.url}")  
public void setUrl( String val) {  
this.url = val;  
System.out.println("==== value ==== " + url);
}
```

This was awesome... finally some progress. I believe I am giving up on changing ConfigurationProperties and using @Value for that matter. With this guy's answer, I can access the beans created at startup. Y'all were probably wondering why I didn't in the first place... still learning. I'm bumping him up. That saved my bacon. https://stackoverflow.com/a/24595685/4028704

The plan now is to create a JdbcTemplate producing bean for each of the regions like this:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "Region1")
public class DbConfigR1  extends TomcatDataSourceConfiguration {

   @Bean(name = "dsRegion1") 
    public DataSource dataSource() { 
        return super.dataSource(); 
    } 

    @Bean(name = "00001") 
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dsRegion1) { 
        return new JdbcTemplate(dsRegion1); 
    } 
}
```

When I call my service, I'll use something like this:

```
public AccessBeans(ServletRequest request, String enterprise_id) {
    ctx = RequestContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(request);
    template = ctx.getBean(enterprise_id, JdbcTemplate.class);
}
```

Still open to better ways or insight into foreseeable issues, etc but this way seems to be about equivalent to my current XML based ways. Thoughts?

Comment: This answer got me just a little closer. Perhaps the question I should have been asking is how to user @Value. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25764459/spring-boot-application-properties-value-not-populating